# How to Export Excel Pivot Table Using Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pivot, pivot-table

I want to export pandas pivot df to excel pivot table using python ,

The exported pivot-table most be connected to the data that on another tab as shown on this image:

[image: Image Shows The Final Exported File.]

If Anybody Could Help, I Appreciate it.

Comment: is your question how to create a pivot table using pandas or how to export it to excel?

Comment: My question is how to export pivot table [df.pivot()] to xlsx file with dynamic pivot, that i can edit the pivot table on excel as shown on the img? @TiTo

Comment: @Ch3steR No It dose not.

Comment: I don’t think that there is a way to achieve that. You could either save your pivot as a new df and than store it to excel using ‘df_pivot.to_excel()’ or store your original df as an excel and than create a pivot table in excel

Comment: @TiTo This take so much time , cause i have multiple pivot table to make, thats why i want to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

what if you:

- export your source dataframe to Excel sheet '*data*'
- Than manually create you 'Excel Pivot' control sheet in Excel
- call this Workbook - "*MyPivotTemplate*"..
- and then just rewrite the '*data*' sheet with other/updated dataframes from python? (if structure is same)..

will that work for you?

because creating an active Excel-Pivot has nothing to do with Pandas-Pivot class.
if you want to automate creating of Excel's Pivot from python, record a VBA Macro in Excel, and then use it from/within python. Check: [Working with VBA Macros](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html)